# How to execute insert queries in One database for another database in Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I need to execute update & insert queries in multiple database of azure in one stored procedure. please help

Comment: Do you need to update one database at a time by querying information on other databases and you need to do this process by running a stored procedure that will be located on each database with the same stored procedure name?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually i have a stored procedure in which insert and update command are written and these command are fired for 2 databases in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to execute the same stored procedure in two different databases, you can keep the same stored procedure in both the databases. If you are referring to cross database queries, then it is not possible directly. However, you can make use of ADF/Databricks to achieve the same.